# Listen to local storage change with React in the App.js component

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to listen to a change in the local storage to run a function, basically when a user token get into the local storage i want to listen to it but it's only finding it when i refresh.

```
const user = JSON.parse(getItem(`user`));

const App = () => {
const [isUser, setIsUser] = useState(false)

if(user){
 setIsUser(true)
}

    return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <div>
                    <Router />
                </div>
            </Provider>  
    );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a useEffect which listens to a storage event change and attach a function to fire on a change event.

```
  useEffect(() => {

    window.addEventListener("storage", e => storageChange(e));

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('storage', e => storageChange(e));
    };
  })


  const storageChange = (storageEvent: StorageEvent) => {
    if (storageEvent.key === keyNameConst) {
      //do something
    }
  }
```

With your code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [isUser, setIsUser] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("storage", e => storageChange(e));
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('storage', e => storageChange(e));
    };
  },[storageChange])


  const storageChange = (storageEvent: StorageEvent) => {
    if (storageEvent.key === "user") {
      const user = JSON.parse(storageEvent.newValue);
      setUser(user);
      setIsUser(true);
    }
  }


  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div>
        <Router />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for some reason it's not grabbing the user token when it's being created on Login

Comment: Have you added the user token to local storage? you would need to call 
window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userToken)); when you actually receive the token

Answer (score 0):

If you want acces to LocalStorage, react-way (reactive) you can write custom hook that will achive this:

https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/